# Finding local extrema of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've been given $f=x^2+4y^2$ defined on the disk $x^2+y^2\leq4$
I need to find local extrema on the interior of the disk, I've partially differentiated f with respect to both $x$ and $y$

When setting the equations to $0$ I obviously get that both $x$ and $y =0$, which doesnt seem right

How would I go about finding these extrema?

Comment: note that your local extrema occur potentially at the critical points OR on the boundary.  You will need to search the boundary as well.  Note that you did find a (global) min at 0,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f=x^2+4y^2=(x^2+y^2)+3y^2 \leq 4+3y^2$$

is maximal for $y=2$ (due to $x^2+y^2 \leq 4$, and therefore $x=0$ ) and minimal for ... I leave it to you...

Comment: Thanks, how did you know to $+3y^2$ to each side?

Comment: I just separated $4 y^2$ into $y^2+3y^2$

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: I think I have the minimal? at $x=2, y=0$ could you please verify

Comment: That's right !...

Comment: There is a residual problem : you are asked maximum and minimum in the interior of the disk. But points $(2,0)$ and $(0,2)$ are on the boundary... Have you seen the maximum modulus theorem ?